# Number of elements in const char * array

Tags: c++, c, pointers, size, sizeof

I have written a function in C which takes as an argument `const char *p` and I would like to check the number of elements in that array, but it doesn't work well.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int arrSize(const char *a){
    int it = 0;
    int size = 0;
    while(a[it] != '\0'){
        ++size;
        ++it;
    }
    return size;
}

int main(){
        const char a[5] = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'v', 's'};
        const char b[4] = {'c', 'b', 'b', 'v'};
        const char c[4] = {'c', 'b', 'b', 'v'};
        printf("%d %d %d", arrSize(a), arrSize(b), arrSize(c));
}
```

But the code above gives 8, 12, 16 output and I don't know why.

Comment: You didn't put a 0 at the end of those arrays.

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages. Please only tag the language you're actually working in.

Comment: As for your problem, it's just what @CostantinoGrana says. Where in your arrays are the `'\0'` null-terminator character?

Comment: Also note that there's a difference between *array size* and *string length*. These two doesn't have to be related. You can have e.g. `char foo[10] = "bar";` The size of the array is `sizeof foo` and will be equal to `10`, while the string length (as reported by e.g. `strlen`) would be `3`. Your code attempts to calculate the string length.

Comment: And on another note, think about the use of `size` and `it` in your function. When will they ever be different? Do you really need both variables?

Comment: It is impossible to tell the size of an array, which is why most program put `\0` at the end and then look for the `\0`.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> while(a[it] != '\0'){
> ```

This loop ends when the element of the array is equal to the null terminator character.

> ```
> const char a[5] = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'v', 's'};
> const char b[4] = {'c', 'b', 'b', 'v'};
> const char c[4] = {'c', 'b', 'b', 'v'};
> ```

None of your arrays contain a null terminator character. The loop won't stop on the elements, and it will access non-existing elements outside of the bounds of the array and the behaviour of the program is undefined. This is bad. Don't do this.

If you add null terminator to the arrays, then the function will successfully count the number of non-null-terminator characters that precede the first null-terminator:

```
const char a[6] = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'v', 's', '\0'};
//const char a[] = "abbvs"; // equivalent
printf("%d", arrSize(a)); // 5
```

Note that there is no need to write this `arrSize` because it's provided by the standard library under the name `strlen`.

---

When you pass a pointer to element of an array into a function, there is no general way to determine the size of the array using that pointer without relying on a terminator value such as in the case of null terminated strings.

When a function needs to access a non-terminated array of arbitrary length, a common C idiom is to pass that size into the function as an argument. Modern C++ idiom is to use `std::span` or equivalent which is essentially same except the compiler can deduce the size of an array.

You can determine the size of an array variable within the scope where the array is declared. A common C idiom is to divide `sizeof` the array with `sizeof` the element type. Modern C++ idiom is to use `std::size`. Example:

```
const char a[5] = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'v', 's'};,
void operate_on_array(const char *arr, size_t size);

// C
operate_on_array(a, sizeof a / sizeof *a);

// C++ with std::size
operate_on_array(a, std::size(a));

// C++ with std::span
operate_on_array(std::span<const char> arr);
operate_on_array(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a string end char `0x0` (or `'\0'`，your function will keep going until a zero-valued memory byte, which is unsafe and out-of-bounds access.

Fix:

*main.cpp* 1:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int arrSize(const char *a) {
  int it = 0;
  int size = 0;
  while (a[it] != '\0') {
    ++size;
    ++it;
  }
  return size;
}

int main() {
  const char a[5 + 1] = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'v', 's', '\0'};
  const char b[4 + 1] = {'c', 'b', 'b', 'v', '\0'};
  const char c[4 + 1] = {'c', 'b', 'b', 'v', '\0'};
  printf("%d %d %d", arrSize(a), arrSize(b), arrSize(c));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put '\0' to the end of array explicitly or initialize it as string:

```
int main(){
    const char a[] = "abbvs";
    const char b[] = "cbbv";
    const char c[] = "cbbv";
    printf("%d %d %d", arrSize(a), arrSize(b), arrSize(c));
    return 0;
}
```

In this case compiler will put '\0' automatically to the end of array.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assume that there is a 0 at the end of the array unless you explicitly set that as an element. (The notation `"abbvs"` - which is a `const char[6]` literal - does that for you.)

The behaviour of accessing an element outside the bounds of the array is undefined. Don't do it.

Use `std::string` instead, or pass the size as a parameter; probably as a `std::size_t` type.

This all said, you could use `std::size(a)` in place of `arrSize(a)` etc. although you will need to change your format specifier to `%zu`. `std::size` uses some clever template trickery to obviate pointer decay.